# PHP - User not staying logged in

Tags: php

I've finally got the courage to make a user login system after who knows how long of putting it off. My only problem is that when I submit the login form it reloads the page and it says that I am logged in, great.

However if I reload the page or go to another page and come back to the original page it forces me to login again. Can anyone help with this? I have a session_start() in the base file that is included in all other page files before the database connection.

I then have the following code for my user login side of things, which as I said, works the first time around, but after that any other interaction will essentially log me out. Any help with this?

The user page which logs you in and creates the session...

**Please note that this isn't a live environment so security is being put on the bench for now. However I am aware I will need some security measures in place in the future though.**

```
// Check if the user is logged in or not
if((!empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['username']))) {

$loggedin = true; // The user IS logged in

} else {

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
// The login form has been submitted

    if((empty($_POST['username'])) || (empty($_POST['password']))) {
    // If either username or password fields are blank

        $loginfail = true; // If the user could not be logged in

        if(empty($_POST['username'])) { $nousername = true; }

        if(empty($_POST['password'])) { $nopassword = true; }

    } else {
    // Username and password field were filled in okay

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $checklogin = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'") or die($checklogin . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($sql));

        if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1) {
        // If the login details match up, log them in

            $loggedin = true; // The user IS NOT logged in

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;

        } else {
        // If the login details don't match up, don't login

            $loginfail = true; // If the user could not be logged in

        }

    }

}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])` and `(isset($_SESSION['username'])` in there somewhere; `!empty` isn't enough. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: I found out what my issue was. I had put the session destroy comment at the top of my page by accident. I was saving it for later to place when I needed to log out. So that's why but I've implemented your suggestions too, they work much better. As always thanks Fred :)

Comment: That's great Dan, glad to hear you found the problem. Always glad to help and you're quite welcome, *cheers*

Comment: Please delete your question